# I am trying to use npm start on Mac terminal and I am getting this error call command not found

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, npm-scripts, npm-start

Hello I am getting this error, I have tired almost everything from online source but nothing is working out, any help will be appreciated, thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvBiT.jpg)

Hello I am getting this error. I have tried everything from online sources but still it’s not working out for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please see [ask], including the section on adding text as text, and not as images -- especially not a blurry picture of your screen.

Comment: try running `npm install`

Comment: I did that already no luck